# Szemerédi’s theorem in really dense sets

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, arithmetic-progression

This question is inspired by Tao’s answer in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414973/a-proof-of-van-der-waerdens-theorem-using-a-weakened-form-of-szemeredis-theore/414978#414978). I have thought about this occasionally for several months without anything concrete.

**Question:**

Given $\delta>0$ and $k\ge 3$, let $N= N_k(\delta)$ be such that for $N’>N$, and $A\subset G:=\Bbb{Z}/N’\Bbb{Z}$ with $|A| > \delta N’$, we have that $A$ contains an arithmetic progression of length $k$ (i.e., there exists $x,d \in G, d\neq 0$ where $P:= \{x,x+d,x+2d,\dots,x+(k-1)d\} \subset A$).

Does there exist some absolute constant $C$, such that $N_k(1-10/k) \le k^{C+o(1)}$ for all large $k$?

**Comments:** The construction from [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419305/can-we-do-better-than-random-when-constructing-dense-k-ap-free-sets) can be applied to show that: fixing any $a\ge 1,\epsilon > 0$, we will have $N_k(1-a/k) \ge k^{(1-\epsilon)a}$ for all sufficiently large $k$. It sounds plausible to me that this may be sharp, in the sense that, for fixed $a\ge 1,\epsilon > 0$, we have $N_k(1-a/k)\le k^{(1+\epsilon)a}$ for all sufficiently large $k$.

I have defined $N_k(\cdot)$ in terms of progression-free subsets of groups, rather than subsets of the interval $\{1,\dots,N\}$. This was simply to make a bit easier to get better upper bounds. I would of course also be interested if anything can be said about the interval variant.

Comment: What is the meaning of $1 - 10/k$ and $C+o(1)$ instead of simply $C$? The question seems to be equivalent to asking for bound $N_k\le k^C$ for large $k$ (possibly with different $C$).

Comment: $N_k(\cdot)$ is function, and 10 is just some arbitrary constant a bit bigger than 1. you are right about $C$ of course, but I find more intuitive to write it this way. if someone proves (say) $N_k\le k^5$ for all $k\ge 10^{1000}$, I find it more helpful to view this as $k^{5+o(1)}$ rather than $k^C$ for some abstract $C$.